# ggsurvplot: How to make the P value bold

Tags: r

```
library("survminer") 
fit2<- survfit(Surv(OS..months., Survival.status) ~ Stra, data = inputdata) 
ggsurvplot(fit2, data = inputdata,
           pval = TRUE)
```

I would like to know how could I change the face of P value?
Thanks

Comment: let me know if it didnt work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the bold text manually

First remove `pval=TRUE` and store in `j`

```
j <- ggsurvplot(fit2, data = inputdata,
           pval = FALSE)
```

Then add

```
j$plot <- j$plot +
     annotate("text", x = 10, y = 15, label = "P-value", cex=3.3, vjust=0, hjust = 1.1, fontface=2)

j
```

Just simply change the `(x,y)-coordinates` for the added Text